# while copying data from Sql server to Databricks delta lake(sql notebook activity) Blank values populating as Null values

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-factory, delta-lake

I am copying data from SQL server through ADF copy activity and storing it in Databricks delta lake with SQL notebook, After storing the data the Blank values storing  as NULL

Source datatype: varchar

Target datatype: String

How to get rid of NULL values and populate them with Blank values at the Target side?

NOT NULL Constraint is not working

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can ***Rid*** ***all NULL*** values and keep them as ***Blank values***. You can follow below codes its working fine for me.

> **Remove selected NULL columns  keep them as Blank values**.

```
select *, ifnull(marks,' ') marks1  from datastore_panels.tb11
```

[image: Ref1]

> **Remove all NULL values  keep them as Blank values**.

```
select Name, subject, ifnull(marks,' ') marks, ifnull(Status,' ') Status, ifnull(Attendance,' ') Attendance   from datastore_panels.tb11
```

[image: Ref2]